# maven can't find path specified

Tags: java, windows, maven

I have some problems building my project with maven on my windows machine and I discovered that even "mvn version"  not completes correctly. It ends with "the system cannot find the path specified"

```
D:\my_project\nl.esi.poosl.maven>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T22:58:10+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\my_project\nl.esi.poosl.maven>
```

**environment variables:**

**PATH:**                   %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;D:\sytemapps\Python27;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;C:\Developer\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\mingw\bin

**JAVA_HOME:**
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

**M2:**
%M2_HOME%\bin

**M2_HOME:** 
C:\apache-maven-3.2.3

I can't find the reason why "The system cannot find the path specified." is printed out because it probably is the reason why my project won't build.

Comment: Some command is executed AFTER Maven. `mvn -v` should end with the OS name. Please run `set MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on` followed by `mvn -v` and analyze the output.

Answer (score 2):

Your %JAVA_HOME% is pointing to a JRE. A JRE usually doesn't have javac. Could this be the source of the issue?

Other than that, my environment is the same as yours and it runs fine.

What does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: Do have the samve java and java version? What is you result? for comparison. My java_home points to the jdk but mvn goes to jre

Comment: I bet its not a problem with your current setup. All of the things you listed are fine. I would check to see if the user that you are logged in as can read all of the directories. It could be an OS permissions issue.

Comment: It's not. `JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`. You are confusing "Java home" with "JAVA_HOME".

Answer (score 0):

%JAVA_HOME%\bin;**%M2%**;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;D:\sytemapps\Python27;%**M2**%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;C:\Developer\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\mingw\bin

change to

%JAVA_HOME%\bin;**%M2_HOME%**;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;D:\sytemapps\Python27;%**M2_HOME**%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;C:\Developer\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin;%DEVKIT_HOME%\mingw\bin

Issue might be becuase of environment variable path name. For maven environment varibale name should be **M2_HOME** or **MAVEN_HOME**(for older version)

Comment: changing it to M2_HOME would and does fail because mvn is present in the \bin folder. I tried %M2_HOME%\bin just to be sure. but same error. Current PATH: %M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 0):

Details for the bounty:

Here is the output to `mvn -v`:
[image]

Comment: Update: This is likely a problem with windows. When I create a new local user and run `mvn -v` it works fine. Anybody already had this issue with Windows ?

Comment: I fixed the issue with this: https://superuser.com/a/727323

Answer (score 0):

In my case,the problem was not with maven nor java.

I fixed it by editing values in regex by following this answer: https://superuser.com/a/727323

Quoted from the answer: "

- Open the Registry Editor (press +R, type regedit and hit Enter) .
- Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun and clear the values.
- Also check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun.

"

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre and post script mechanism in the `mvn.bat`.
The `%HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat` and the `%HOME%\mavenrc_post.bat` files. They are executed before and after the maven executable.

It is possible that the `mavenrc_post.bat` file is exists in your path and it contains something what can not be found during the `mvn -v`.

This usually happens on corporate machines when the administrators sets something up there.

You can validate it by two ways:

1. Set the `MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO` as it was commented by Robert Scholte (`set MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on`). This will echo the batch commands so you can figure out which command causes the error message.
2. You can disable the pre and post rc execution by setting the `MAVEN_SKIP_RC` to anything (`set MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true`).

*Note*: The `mvn.bat` is tricky about the location of the `%HOME%` as it allows overrides but by default that is the `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I fixed my issue with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65145769/3971619. I'll give you the bounty reputations since you don't have a lot of reputation

Comment: Thanks! I hope my answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (and step forward) try with Maven Wrapper:

https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper

```
mvnw.cmd clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an JavaFX application using Maven, you don't have to download the JavaFX SDK. You can just specify the modules and the versions you want in the pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

add above plugin and the dependency into the pom file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

No SDK, No path setting. It works for me.
[You may find further help in this open jfx documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)